# Pipeline script vbs

Tags: vbscript

I created the following script, but it only returns 0, even finding errors in DNS test.

```
Dim consult, objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")

consult = objShell.run ("dcdiag /test:DNS | findstr /i failed", 0)

If consult = "0" THEN
    WScript.Echo "OK"
else
    WScript.Echo "ERROR"
end If
```

I understand that is not running the findstr.

Thank attention.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't use "Option Explicit"; that's reckless.
- You don't init near/immediately after your Dims; that's error prone.
- You use variables (objShell) just once; that's wasteful.
- You mix data types (integer vs string) in a comparison; that's stupid.
- You don't read the Docs (carefully); that's impertinent.

From the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

*bWaitOnReturn*

> Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for
>   the program to finish executing before continuing to the next
>   statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until
>   the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the
>   program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns
>   immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not
>   to be interpreted as an error code).

To avoid unnecessary problems caused by missing dcdiag or different versions of findstr or mis-understanding/use of those programs, I use "minimal errorlevel setters":

```
type ex0.vbs, ex1.vbs

ex0.vbs
WScript.Quit 0

ex1.vbs
WScript.Quit 1
```

and this code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim consult : consult = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("%comspec% /c ex0.vbs | ex1.vbs", 0, True)

If consult = "0" THEN
    WScript.Echo consult, "OK"
else
    WScript.Echo consult, "ERROR"
end If
```

output:

```
cscript 36531325.vbs
1 ERROR
```

Use

```
.Run("ex0.vbs | ex1.vbs", 0, True)
```

to see that you need a shell (%comspec%) to use a shell's features (|) and

```
.Run("%comspec% /c ex0.vbs | ex1.vbs", 0)
```

for understandig the importance of the bWaitOnReturn parameter.